# Why would messages in Exchange 2010 R1 with 0 SCL scores end up in Junk Mail folder?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, spam

We have Hub Transport rules that mark e-mail messages with a 0 SCL score if they meet certain criteria. However, some messages that should be caught by these rules are still ending up in the Junk Mail folder.

We have confirmed via e-mail headers that the messages *did* get the 0 SCL score.

What else shuold we look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook has it's own junk mail filtering rules, and I'm pretty sure they pay no attention to the SCL assigned by Exchange.  Try turning off all junk mail filtering in Outlook and I would bet that the issue would disappear.

Comment: If you know how I'd audit this for users using non-MAPI cients, please see my [related question](http://serverfault.com/questions/319750/how-do-i-audit-users-mailbox-action-performed-via-imap-in-exchange-2010-to-work).