# How do I audit user's mailbox actions performed via IMAP in Exchange 2010?

Tags: security, email, exchange, exchange-2010

I read through the [Technet article on Mailbox auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459237.aspx) but it seems to only be working for MAPI access.

I perform the following cmdlet to enable auditing of the owner:

```
> Set-Mailbox -Identity "Mr. Mel-Bin" -AuditEnabled $true -AuditOwner Create,SoftDelete,HardDelete,Update,Move,MoveToDeletedItems
```

That does not return any output. Then, I move some messages in the mailbox using IMAP client and peform the following cmdlet to see if the auditing worked:

```
>Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity bfernan -LogonTypes Owner -ShowDetails -StartDate 10/9/2011
```

This returns no output. Is there something I am overlooking or does Exchange 2010 just not audit IMAP access?

Comment: You are setting the owner audit properties. Are you using the "Mr. Mel-Bin" account to log in through IMAP?

Comment: @syneticon-dj yes I am.

Comment: Mmh. Could you add the -ShowDetails parameter to Search-MailboxAuditLog?

Comment: @syneticon-dj I modified the command. This one returns no output.

Comment: I have no further questions, your honor. But no ideas either. It would not be the first time when certain kind of functionality is limited to MAPI acces. You might ask in the [support forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/threads) for an official statement - Microsoft employees which could simply ask the responsible product group are reading and answering there.

Comment: Very well. You may step down. (Thanks @syneticon-dj! I'll ask there)

Comment: I've noticed using Mailbox instead of Identity works well for some PS commands, it may help in your situation if possible with the cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

- Is IMAP configured to report the changes *back to the server*? Or is it just doing the move *"locally"*?
- Have you tried with e.g. *OWA* to see if auditing works using plain exchange?
- You use 2 different `"-Identity"` strings, can you use the same for both commands?